# Laravel Eloquent create composite key that uses autoincrements

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a migration like below

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('order_num');
        $table->timestamps();
```

The primary key should be a combination of id and order_num. If I put the below code, it says I'm trying to add 2 primary keys (because the increments is also a primary key). Is there a way to tell eloquent that I'm trying to bunch the two together

```
        $table->primary(['course_id', 'order_num']);
```

Comment: what table is your first snippet of code? I guess you have orders table but what is the other

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit more about the situation? `Increments` generates a unique, auto increment id for each row. You don't need to add anything to it in order to make it unique. I can't see a reason for a composite primary key when one of the columns involved is already unique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you're using **MySQL**.

First of all, the default MySQL engine **InnoDB** doesn't allow composite primary keys where one of the fields would be autoincrement. The engine that allows that is **MyISAM**, so the first thing you need to do is to change the engine for the table.

You can do that by adding the following to your table definition:

```
$table->engine = 'MyISAM';
```

The next issue you need to tackle is the fact that Laravel's schema builder assumes, that the column you set as **autoincrement** is your primary key. That;s why you're getting the error about primary key existing already - Laravel already made the **id** field the primary key.

To solve this issue, you need to declare **id** field as normal integer column, define all other columns and at the end declare the composite primary key. It could look like that:

```
$table->integer('id');
$table->integer('order_num');
$table->timestamps();
$table->primary(['course_id', 'order_num']);
```

This way you have created a composite primary key. The only thing that is missing is the autoincrement attribute on **id** column. Laravel's schema builder doesn't provide methods to alter existing columns, that's why you'll need to run raw SQL queries. The query you need is:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
```

**To sum up, your migration's up() method could look like following:**

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'MyISAM';

    $table->integer('id');
    $table->integer('order_num');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->primary(['course_id', 'order_num']);
  });

  DB::statement('ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
}
```